# Unity permission problem while creating asset bundles from code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the followinf piece of code:

```
[MenuItem("Test/Test")]
static void Test()
{
    var buildMap = new AssetBundleBuild[1];
    buildMap[0].assetBundleName = "MyBundleName";
    buildMap[0].assetNames = new string[1] { "Assets/Resources/Thumbnails/Abs001.jpg" };   
    BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/Resources/AssetBundles", buildMap, BuildAssetBundleOptions.ChunkBasedCompression, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);    
}
```

It suppose to create an asset bundle with this one file in it. But when I run it I get an error "Creating directory Library/ScriptAssemblies failed. Please ensure there is enough disk space and you have permissions setup correctly."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9xct.jpg

I never had it before. Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: As the description says, do you have enough of disk space and do you have the user permissions to this specific folder?

Comment: wow it turned out I have to disable readonly setting on the library folder becasue Unity set it bact to true every time. Thanks man!

Comment: No problem. I've added the answer so you can mark it up. Take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the description says, do you have enough of disk space and do you have the user permissions to this specific folder? Check those out as I've said the problem is described pretty well.